# The characteristic (indicator) function of a set is not in the Sobolev space H¹

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

> Is it true that the characteristic
> (indicator) function of a subset of
> Euclidean space with finite positive
> measure is never in the Sobolev space
> $H^1 = W^{1,2}$? And if so, what is the best/easiest/most elementary way to see this?

Context:

I have this on good authority (it is stated in a decent textbook). However, I have had no joy in showing this to be the case myself. Due to its placement in the aforementioned textbook as the first exercise at the end of a chapter about $H^1$, it feels like it oughtn't be difficult to show, but a group of my friends and I had no luck. It is bugging me now.

[Though I am a student taking a course based on the textbook, this is not ‘homework’; I will not be graded on it in any way and I have attempted the problem myself.]

Comment: In your attempt, what definition of $W^{1,2}$ did you use?

Comment: Well, those functions in $L^2$ all of whose weak first derivatives are given by $L^2$ functions. 

Comment: It is even never in $H^{1/2}$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763330/charcteristic-function-not-in-a-fractional-sobolev-space/3772031#3772031

Answer (score 7):

One reason is this: if $f$ is in $H^1({\mathbb R^n})$, you have $\int_{\mathbb R^n}|f(x+h)-f(x)|^2 dx\le C|h|^2$ for all $h \in{\mathbb R^n}$ . Now in the case of $f:=\chi_E$ the integral is just the $L^1$ distance, $\|\chi_E - \chi_{E-h}\|_1$. By the triangular inequality, for any positive integer m and any h as above one gets

$\|\chi_E -\chi_{E-h}\|_1 \le$

$\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\|\chi_{E - \frac{j}{m} h } - \chi_{E-\frac {j+1}{m}h}\|_1 \le$

$Cm|h/m|^2=C|h|^2/m$,

whence $\|\chi_E - \chi_{E-h}\|_1=0$ for all $h$. This is impossible since for $|h|\to\infty$ it converges to 2meas(E).

Comment: Any chance you could please just give extra clarification as to where the $m$'s come from? Many thanks.

Comment: @ Pietro, I'm not sure about your first inequality- what if n=1 and f(x) is x^2 ? Trying h=1 for example seems to scupper things...

Comment: (I tried to edit but had some problem with TeX). Anyway: just apply the first inequality to h/m where m is a positive integer, and make m steps to estimate the distance between E and E-h. Since m is arbitrary you conclude. Is it everything OK to you? This is quite an elementary proof.

Comment: @Tom, x^2 is  not in H1(R)  :) 

Comment: My mistake! Chop it, bump it, mollify it and extend it by zero- I'm convinced you're still going to get a higher power of h than 2! Maybe I'm just being silly, but I swear I've never seen that inequality... Any chance you've got a reference for it?

Comment: Actually for L2 functions that inequality is a characterization of H1. This stuff is quite popular in calculus of variations and regularity. To prove the inequality, do it first for smooth functions with compact support (just write f(x+h)-f(x) as integral of the derivative in the direction h, then use Cauchy-Schwartz and Fubini. You will find C=||Df||_2^2). Then pass to the limit. An analog result holds with all p>1, to characterize W^{1,p}; with p=1 you get BV. Reference: I think Brezis (Fun.Anal.) is OK. 


Comment: Aha! Found it in Dracorogna- never did follow calculus of variations as far as I should- nowhere to be found in my PDE books... You sir, have well and truly earned yourself a +1! Much more elegant than mine- which seems 'pretty sledgehammer to crack a nut' by comparison...

Comment: Thank you, my pleasure. Your argument is more general in that also proves that chi_E is not W^1,1, nor W^1,1_loc; the argument I used at most covers W1,p for p>1. :)

Comment: (erratum corrige: oh I wrote "Schwartz" instead of "Schwarz")

Comment: Maybe the last line of the argument could simply be: therefore $\chi_E(x)=\chi_E(x+h)$ a.e. for any $x$ and $h$, that is, $\chi\equiv0$ or $\chi\equiv1$ everywhere, both cases being forbidden

Answer (score 5):

A not-so-elementary way to see it is to use the theorem that if $f$ is an $H^1$ function, then for almost every line segment, the restriction of $f$ to that line segment gives an absolutely continuous function.  (In fact, this is essentially sufficient as well as necessary.) Wikipedia cites Maz'ya's book *Sobolev spaces*, and I also found a proof in [Ziemer](http://books.google.com/books?id=2_vUE9VWghsC&lpg=PA48&ots=n8dL_dOzRS&dq=sobolev%20absolutely%20continuous%20lines&pg=PA44#v=onepage&q=sobolev%20absolutely%20continuous%20lines&f=false).

Answer (score 4):

If it's in $H^1$ it's a.e. differentiable, with weak differential a.e. equal its differential, which for an indicator function is a.e. zero. So if you integrate any candidate for your weak derivative multiplied by a compactly supported test function you should get zero. Now if you use the right test function and the definition of a weak derivative you ought to be able to contrive a contadiction of the form "$0=1$".

Comment: Does this arguement avoid assuming that the boundary of the set is of measure zero? 

I might be overcomplicating things but it's something that worried me last time I thought about the problem.

Comment: Just an objection: if f is differentiable in a point, it should continuous, hence locally bounded in that point, which is not quite true in H<sup>1</sup> if n>1 (such an f may have a dense set of singularities). 

Comment: @Pietro- if it's in H1 it will be a.e. differentiable- even the stuff with a dense set of singularities has that going for it. Don't worry- it's definitely a theorem ;)

Comment: @Spencer- It does. You just need to use the fact that there is an open ball which intersects with the set you are indicating in a set of measure zero (this is where your function 'goes up') and then let it 'roll down' over a subset of positive measure of the set you are indicating.

Comment: @Tom: By singularity I really mean blow up of the function. What theorem do you mean? Certainly not about differentiability a.e.; Rademacher's thm only works in W^1,infty. Oh, maybe by "differentiable a.e." you mean just having all partial derivatives a.e.; I see.  

Comment: Another argument would be using the fact that any function in W^{1,1}_loc(R^n)  has a.e. continuous 1 dimensional sections (in fact, for all v in R^n and a.e. x in R^n, the 1 variable function u(t):=f(x+ty) is W^{1,1}_loc(R).) de hoc satis. 

Comment: But say \chi_([0,1]) in L^2(R) would be a.e. cts wouldn't it? Or am I dropping another x^2 in H^1 clanger?

Comment: Excuse me Tom, what do you mean ?

Comment: Is your alternative arument saying: "If it were in W^{1,1}_loc(R^n) it would be a.e cts wrt sections, but indicator functions are not QED" because if so, I'm not sure that indicator functions are in general not a.e. cts.

Comment: I'm making a bit stronger statement: if f is in W^{1,1}_loc(R^n) and v is in R^n, then, for a.e. x in R^n, the function of 1 real variable u(t):=f(x+tv) is (in W^{1,1}_loc(R) hence) continuous : not just a.e. continuous (in particular this implies that f has a.e. partial derivatives, which is the theorem you referred to, I think).  
This way we can easily conclude. Actually this argument should be just a variation of yours.

Comment: But isn't, say x^(-2) in W^{1,1}_loc(R)?

Comment: of course it is not... W^{1,1}_loc(R) functions are continuous (or if you like, they have a continuous representant). W^1,1[a,b]=AC[a,b].

Comment: Tom what you have said here is **false**. See Evans chapter 5. If a function is in $W^{1,p}$ where $p > n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then indeed what you said is true. So for one dimension, we do indeed have that $H^1 \subset C^0$. However this is not true in general. We only know there *exists* some weak derivative. We do not a priori know anything about almost everywhere differentiability of our function when $p < n$.


Answer (score 3):

The [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/25156) posted by Tom, as written is actually not true. A function in $H^1$ will not in general be differential almost everywhere; it depends on the dimension. In one dimension however it is indeed true that $H^1$ functions are differentiable almost everywhere (they are in fact absolutely continuous). There are two ways of seeing it is not in $H^1$. The simple answer is that if you differentiate the characteristic function of say $[0,\infty)$ then you will get the Dirac measure. However let me just answer your question first:

**Answer 1:**
Take any smooth compactly supported $\phi:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. By definition of  weak derivative we have
$\int \phi\, g^{\prime} \,\mathrm dx = - \int \phi^{\prime} g \,\mathrm dx$ where I've set $g=1_{[0,\infty)}$. This would have to be true for all such $\phi$ if the weak derivative existed. Now take $\phi^{\epsilon}$ to be supported in a neighborhood $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ of $0$. We are making the crucial assumption that $g^{\prime}$ is an **integrable** and hence it follows that $\int \phi^{\epsilon} g^{\prime} \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. However, $\phi^{\epsilon}$ is smooth and so
$\int \partial_x\phi^{\epsilon}(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx = \phi^{\epsilon}(0)$ since $\phi$ was assumed to have compact support in $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. Now just fix $\phi^{\epsilon}(0)=1$ and we have that $\phi^{\epsilon}(0) \to 0$ by the first integral equality. This is a clear contradiction.

Notice that in fact that this really shows that $g' \,\mathrm dx = \delta(x)$.

**Answer 2:**
Take $1_{[0,1]}$ instead so that it is an $L^2([0,1])$ function. This is in fact the Fourier transform of a "sinc" function, $\sin(k)/k$ up to some normalization constants. If we consider the $H^1$ norm in frequency space we would need $\int_0^{\infty} |k|^2\frac{\sin(k)^2}{|k|^2} \,\mathrm d k < \infty$ which is clearly false. This requires being at ease with the Fourier transform so if you're not, answer 1 is probably best.

It is true in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that if $u \in W^{1,p}$ for $p > n$ then $u$ is a.e. differentiable and equals a.e. its weak gradient (see Evans chapter 5). This is to correct what Tom had said although perhaps we was thinking about the $n=1$ case in which case $2 > 1$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answers are in dimension 1, that is, exactly when the answer you disagree with is correct ;)